# Подскажите библиотеки MediaPlayer (Audio)

Tags: android, framework, mediaplayer, android-mediaplayer

Необходимо проигрывать радио-поток (htttp).

1) Пробовал стандартный AndroidSDK-mediaPlayer, но при проигрывании потока некоторые методы просто не вызываются, хотя должны.

2) Пробовал Vitamio. Но с этой библиотекой приложение не проходит модерацию на Google Play.

Какие еще есть библиотеки для проигрывания аудио-потока?

Answer (score 1):

ExoPlayer от Google
[Сорцы здесь](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)